# How to do ANOVA test to compare the performance of different clustering algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, anova

I am trying to compare the performance of the different clustering algorithm results (k-means++ and hierarchical agglomerative clustering) applied to the same dataset. I have 4 different results in total (2 of them have KPCA preprocessing, 2 of them do not have), that is why I chose ANOVA to conclude which one yielded the best result.

However, I do not know what input to give the ANOVA test. Can anyone suggest which data I should take from the algorithm results to provide input? (I am using Python language and sci-kit learn)

Answer (score 0):

The use of ANOVA here is likely a bad idea.

Since k-means tries to minimize within cluster variance, this will pollute a variance based analysis.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116294/appropriateness-of-anova-after-k-means-cluster-analysis